# How do I search for a specific string in a JSON Postgres data type column?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a column named `params` in a table named `reports` which contains JSON.

I need to find which rows contain the text 'authVar' anywhere in the JSON array. I don't know the path or level in which the text could appear.

I want to just search through the JSON with a standard like operator.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM reports
WHERE params LIKE '%authVar%'
```

I have searched and googled and read the Postgres docs. I don't understand the JSON data type very well, and figure I am missing something easy.

The JSON looks something like this.

```
[  
   {  
      "tileId":18811,
      "Params":{  
         "data":[  
            {  
               "name":"Week Ending",
               "color":"#27B5E1",
               "report":"report1",
               "locations":{  
                  "c1":0,
                  "c2":0,
                  "r1":"authVar",
                  "r2":66
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

In **Postgres 11 or earlier** it is possible to recursively walk through an unknown json structure, but it would be rather complex and costly. I would propose the *brute force* method which should work well:

```
select *
from reports
where params::text like '%authVar%';
-- or 
-- where params::text like '%"authVar"%';
-- if you are looking for the exact value
```

The query is very fast but may return unexpected extra rows in cases when the searched string is a part of one of the keys.

In **Postgres 12+** the recursive searching in JSONB is pretty comfortable with the new feature of `jsonpath`.

Find a string value containing *authVar*:

```
select *
from reports
where jsonb_path_exists(params, '$.** ? (@.type() == "string" && @ like_regex "authVar")')
```

The jsonpath:

```
$.**                     find any value at any level (recursive processing)
?                        where
@.type() == "string"     value is string
&&                       and
@ like_regex "authVar"   value contains 'authVar'
```

Or find the exact value:

```
select *
from reports
where jsonb_path_exists(params, '$.** ? (@ == "authVar")')
```

Read in the documentation:

- [The SQL/JSON Path Language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH)
- [jsonpath Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH)

Comment: What would be the advantage of recursively walking through?

Comment: This tutorial explains the "params::text" in detail: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/

Comment: @CaleSweeney - This simple solution will fail when we're searching for an attribute which is the same as one of keys.

Comment: Is there a way to use "jsonb_path_exists" with multiple params and case insensitive?

Comment: @ersu - yes, read [9.15.2.2. Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#JSONPATH-REGULAR-EXPRESSIONS) in the docs.

Comment: I had to upgrade to Postgres 13 to work. In 12 the function jsonb_path_exists couldn't be found. In docs it exists in Postgres 12: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html

Comment: @IasminiGomes - The function exists and works in Postgres 12 - [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9ae94ebedd5f1fa069357a40d2450c80)

Comment: @klin Do you know if there is any difference between these two expressions: 
`where jsonb_path_exists(params, '$.** ? (@.type() == "string" && @ like_regex "authVar")')` vs `where params @? '$.** ? (@.type() == "string" && @ like_regex "string" flag "i")'` ?