# Postgres check if value exists in a json field (without knowing key)

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.4

I have a json column in `postgresql`, with a structure like so:

`json_col`:

```
{
"key1":["value1","value1.1"],
"key2":["value2"]
}
```

This would be one field in one row. I don't know the names of the keys. What I want to get is to get the row that contains the above json field without querying by a key but querying by value name (ex: `value1` in this case).

To query for a key I use:

`SELECT * FROM table where (json_col -> 'key1')::jsonb is not null;`

This gets me what I want but via `key1` which, in reality, I do not know the name of.  Is there a way to directly query for `json` value?

**(or part of a `json` value works too for me, ex: `...LIKE '%alue%'`)**

Comment: See [How do I search for a specific string in a JSON Postgres data type column?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45849743/1995738)

Answer (score 1):

In postgres 9.4 try this :

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each_text(json_col) AS c
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(c.value :: text[]) AS v(value)
 WHERE v.value LIKE '%value%'
```