# SQLAlchemy: Case-insensitve search over JSON data in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to search through data in a JSON column in my Postgresql database, with wildcards and case insensitive.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45849743/4784914) I have seen I could make a query like:

```
WHERE LOWER(data::text) LIKE '%<keyword>%'
```

This works, but now I'm stuck on how to achieve this in SQLAlchemy. How can I get this `::text` suffix? And how would I do `LOWER(...)` on this intermediate expression?

I've been looking for something like this, but it results in syntax errors:

```
        filter_condition = func.lower(Table.data.text())).contains(search)

        stmt = (
            select(Table)
            .filter(filter_condition)
            # ... rest of the query
        )

        print(stmt)
```

Comment: Use ILIKE (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/zMpfn-66)), which leads to the question/answer: [PostgreSQL ILIKE query with SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363836/postgresql-ilike-query-with-sqlalchemy)

Comment: `ILIKE` doesn't seem to exist for a JSON `::text` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the JSON `column` to text, then apply the lower function to it before using contains >>

```
 from sqlalchemy import select, func
    
    # Assuming Table.data is your JSON column
    filter_condition = func.lower(Table.data.cast(sqlalchemy.Text)).contains(func.lower('%<keyword>%'))
    
    stmt = (
        select(Table)
        .filter(filter_condition)
    )
    
    print(stmt)
```

Comment: Perfect! Honestly I hadn't realized `::text` is equivalent to CAST (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cast/).